# Trouble with one click, two form subsmissions

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

My goal is for the user to fill out one form and use JavaScript to post the form into two places and I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrod/M7Bfb/) to that end.

1. There is one form with an `input[type='submit']` button on it.
2. When the user submits the form, jQuery intercepts the form, sets a flag, and submits it to the alternate location via AJAX.
3. Upon success, the AJAX callback triggers the form to submit again. The JS notices the flag set in (2) and allows the submission to to occur naturally.

The problem is that the second submission never happens. If I click the button a second time, the form does the full POST so that tells me the logic is correct. Is there a restriction on how many times the browser can submit a form per user action? Why isn't this working?

Comment: Logically, I'd say yes, as it would allow a malicious site to charge you twice for a product you buy (For instance). Browsers usually send a confirm to a user asking him if he wants to refresh the page even though a POST request was sent.

Comment: You might want to trigger another event (for the 2nd attempt) in your success function, and in your click event, put e.preventDefault() in the end of it the click event (and of course add e as a parameter to that function) to prevent the full page postback.  But without more details and seeing your code, it's difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @MacGyver I created a fiddle to demonstrate my code. http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrod/M7Bfb/

Comment: @Truth I'm not trying to do a page refresh so I wouldn't expect to see that confirmation dialog displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajax() call to submit form to your alternativee location via AJAX, and on success event you could submit it to its original location.

Check out the code: http://jsfiddle.net/M7Bfb/2/

Comment: Exactly what I was writing at the same time :)

Comment: Isn't that essentially what I did, only I used the jQuery form plugin?